# PhD programs in Maths

Tags: phd, application

I am a first gen masters student and I hope to get into a PhD program in Applied Math. My grades are honestly okay. I am a solid B student and every now and then I get an A.
School has ways been a challenge for me and I have recently been diagnosed with cptsd. There are days where it’s difficult to do much. Recently it has gotten a lot better. My main saving grace is that my professors like me and I have a paper from undergrad and a paper from my masters that are part of my application. I am trying to get an A- for my classes this semester to help my GPA and might take a class in the fall also.
I want to know, is it possible to get in somewhere? Is my condition something I share in a vague way for my personal statement? Everyone tells me its incredibly competitive so I’m very nervous. I was thinking of getting a job at a research lab after I graduate to help my application as well.

Comment: it definitely explains a lot that I wasnt aware of. thank you!